# MySQL Query - Get all reviews of followed users

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I wonder how I could make this more efficient. Unfortunately it is very slow because the tables have many rows.

I want to get all reviews of users the user 1 followed:

```
SELECT r.id, r.title

FROM followers f

LEFT JOIN reviews r ON r.user_id = f.followers_id

WHERE 

f.user_id = 1 AND
r.user_id = f.follower_id

ORDER BY r.`id`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need more information to help you. Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ especially the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question

Comment: your query looks good, the number of records will have little effect on the performance, unless you are querying millions of records. You can try using `EXPLAIN` if you want to analyze the query. Also, indexing the FK will improve the performance

Comment: Is there both `follower_id` and `followers_id` ?  Or is that a typo?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you don't want `null`s in the results so there is no need for a `LEFT JOIN`, although by setting the condition:

```
r.user_id = f.follower_id
```

which does exist in the `ON` clause also in the `WHERE` clause what you actually get is an `INNER JOIN` because all unmatched rows are filtered out.
Try this:

```
SELECT r.id, r.title
FROM reviews r INNER JOIN followers f
ON r.user_id = f.follower_id
WHERE f.user_id = 1 
ORDER BY r.id
```

or by filtering the table `followers` and then joining:

```
SELECT r.id, r.title
FROM reviews r 
INNER JOIN (SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id = 1) f
ON r.user_id = f.follower_id 
ORDER BY r.id
```

or this:

```
SELECT id, title
FROM reviews 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id = 1) 
ORDER BY id
```

Indexes on the columns `user_id` of `reviews` and `user_id`, `follower_id` of `followers` would really speed the query.

Answer (score 0):

If table has lots of rows than we can make query faster using indexing. So In this case, If we add index on followers.follower_id, reviews.user_id and followers.user_id

Note - If followers.follower_id, reviews.user_id and followers.user_id are either primary or foreign key then these will already have indexes.

You have not written query properly,proper query will be -

**SELECT r.id, r.title
FROM followers f
LEFT JOIN reviews r ON r.user_id = f.followers_id
WHERE 
f.user_id = 1 AND
ORDER BY r.`id`;**

- No Need to use - **r.user_id = f.follower_id** because it is already included in join condition
- Query can not be faster than this. You can make it run faster only if you increase the size of hardware (RAM and #Core) where MySql is installed.

I hope this helps, comment if u have further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

The `LEFT JOIN` doesn't make sense.  You want to return rows from `reviews`, so you want matches.

I would suggest that you try `EXISTS`

```
SELECT r.*
FROM reviews r
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM followers f
              WHERE r.user_id = f.followers_id AND
                    f.user_id = 1
             )
ORDER BY r.id;
```

Then for this query, you want an index on `followers(followers_id, user_id`).  Presumably `reviews.id` is already a primary key.